# Insecure Connection error Firefox v 53.0

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am using selenium 3.4.0 , firefox version 53.0 and gecko driver 0.16.1 , java compiler 1.7.

For some sites insecure connection error is displayed.

I have used firefox profile object as follow but still it's not resolving:

```
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
        profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128);


        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with Selenium 3.4.0 with Mozilla Firefox browser 53.x you need to download the latest geckodriver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Save it in your machine & provide the absolute path of the geckodriver.

Create a new Firefox profile manually by the name `debanjan` and use the `AcceptUntrustedCertificates` & `setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer` options.

This code executes fine with some simple tweak to your own code.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("debanjan");
    testprofile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    testprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
    testprofile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    testprofile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
    testprofile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128);
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, testprofile);
    dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using firefox below `48` version. You won't face any problem or include below code in your existing code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin" ,"C:/Users/siddhesh.kalgaonkar/AppData/Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");
```

It should solve your problem because this is what I use for current firefox version.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox 54.0 64bit, Selenium v3.4.0, jcommender v1.7, TestNG v6.9.9, Java v8.0, Gecko driver v0.17.0

Use below code-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class AppUrl {
public static WebDriver driver;
public static final String url = "https://10.10.1.1";

@BeforeTest

public void setup() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Users/Downloads/geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
     driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
    driver.get(url);
    }
}
```

Even I tried other sample codes from different sites. Today after I upgrade all the softwares and run the code, it worked for me.